# Elasticsearch - completion suggester payload transforming, returns invalid JSON

Tags: json, elasticsearch

I am trying to use the elasticsearch [completion suggester](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-suggesters-completion.html). I have app_user objects, which come into my elasticsearch instance via a couchdb river.

This is the mapping I use:

```
{
    "app_user" : {
        "_all" : {"enabled" : true},
        "_source" : {
            "includes" : [
                "_id",
                "_rev",
                "type",
                "profile.callname",
                "profile.fullname",
                "email"
            ]
        },
        "properties" : {
            "suggest" : { "type" : "completion",
                          "index_analyzer" : "simple",
                          "search_analyzer" : "simple",
                          "payloads" : true
            }
        },
        "transform" : [
            {"script": "ctx._source.suggest = ['input':[ctx._source.email, ctx._source.profile.fullname, ctx._source.profile.callname]]"},
            {"script": "ctx._source.suggest.payload = ['_id': ctx._source['_id'], 'type': ctx._source['type'], '_rev': ctx._source['_rev']]"}
            ,
            {"script": "ctx._source.suggest.payload << ['label': ctx._source.profile.fullname, 'text': ctx._source.email]"}
        ]
    }
}
```

So I am trying to include the object ID and a display text in the payload.
When I view the generated document via `http://localhost:9200/myindex/app_user/<someid>?pretty&_source_transform`, everything seems OK:

```
{
    "_index": "myindex",
    "_type": "app_user",
    "_id": "<someid>",
    "found": true,
    "_source": {
        "_rev": "2-dcd7b9d456e205d3e9d859fdc2c6a688",
        "_id": "<someid>",
        "email": "joni@example.org",
        "suggest": {
            "input": [
                "joni@example.org",
                ...
            ],
            "output": "joni surname - joni@example.org",
            "payload": {
                "_id": "<someid>",
                "type": "app_user",
                "_rev": "2-dcd7b9d456e205d3e9d859fdc2c6a688",
                "label": "joni surname",
                "text": "joni@example.org"
            }
        },
        "type": "app_user",
        "profile": {
            "callname": "",
            "fullname": "joni surname"
        }
    }
}
```

However, when I try to get the document via _suggest, elasticsearch API somehow breaks the JSON object `payload`:

```
curl -XGET "http://localhost:9200/myindex/_suggest" -d '{
    "all-suggest": {
        "text": "joni",
        "completion": {
            "field": "suggest"
        }
    }
}'
```

results in

```
{"_shards":{"total":5,"successful":5,"failed":0},"all-suggest":[{"text":"joni","offset":0,"length":5,"options":[{"text":"joni surname - joni@example.org","score":1.0,"payload"::)
�_id`<someid>�typeIapp_user�_reva2-dcd7b9d456e205d3e9d859fdc2c6a688�label�joni surname�textSjoni@example.org�}]}]}
```

which is definitely no valid JSON.. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is actually a bug in elasticsearch. It was reported and acknowledged [here](https://github.com/elasticsearch/elasticsearch/issues/8959) and should be [fixed shortly](https://github.com/nik9000/elasticsearch/commit/2346586f2cee20bf551bc78704426d727464f15d).

Comment: fixed now: https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch/commit/a95d75e074488b431e014729e17d719798e62c29